# Django DateTimeField()

Tags: django, django-models

In Django: I have a date and time that I need to enter into my database model, which has a column `models.DateTimeField()`. It seems that no matter what I do, I get a ValidationError: enter a valid date/time format.

I have a string like this:

```
myStr = "2011-10-01 15:26"
```

I want to do:

```
 p = mytable(myDate = WHAT_GOES_HERE)

 p.save()
```

Please don't point me to a duplicate question. I have looked around and they point to other questions which again point to questions, which point to some documentaton, which just doesn't get me what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> myStr = "2011-10-01 15:26"
>>> WHAT_GOES_HERE = datetime.datetime.strptime(myStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
>>> WHAT_GOES_HERE
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 15, 26)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 1):

From the Django documentation:

```
# inserting datetime.now()
import django.utils.timezone as tz
mytable.objects.create(myDate=tz.localtime())

# inserting any date:
import pytz
import django.utils.timezone as tz
from datetime import datetime as dt
my_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest')
my_date = dt(2018, 8, 20, 0)
mytable.objects.create(myDate=tz.make_aware(my_date, my_tz))
```

Comment: Instead of _ValidationError: enter a valid date/time format_, I got a _RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField_. In any case the problem was solved by the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
    myStr = '2011/10/01 15:26'
```

And then when creating your object just use myStr as an attribute value:

```
    p = mytable(myDate = myStr)
    p.save()
```