# Django DateTimeField User Input

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime

So I'm trying to populate a model in django using a postgres (postgis) database.  The problem I'm having is inputting the datetimefield. I have written a population script but every time I run it I get the error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "pub_date" violates not-null constraint`. The code below shows my model and the part of the population script that applies to the table.

The model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique_for_date="pub_date")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    article_keywords = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=8), size=8,)
    title_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And the population script:

```
def populate():
    add_article(
        id = "1",
        article_title = "Obama scrambles to get sceptics in Congress to support Iran nuclear deal",
        pub_date = "2015-04-06T20:38:59Z",
        article_keywords = "{obama, iran, debate, congress, america, un, republican, democrat, nuclear, isreal}",
        title_id = "white-house-scrambles-sceptics-congress-iran-nuclear-deal",
        section_id = "us-news",
        location_id = "1"
        )

def add_article(id, article_title, pub_date, article_keywords, title_id, section_id, location_id):
    article = Article.objects.get_or_create(article_title=article_title)[0]
    article.id
    article.article_title
    article.pub_date
    article.article_keywords
    article.title_id
    article.section_id
    article.location_id
    article.save()
    return article

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Newsmap population script..."

    populate()
```

I've searched around for ages but there seems to be no solution to this specific problem. Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: can you try pubdate as datetime object like datetime.datetime(2015, 04, 06, 20, 38, 59)

Comment: do you mean inputting the datetime as `pub_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 04, 06, 20, 38, 59)`. I just tried this and got the same error.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855607/django-datetimefield maybe that helps.

Comment: pub_date field is returning null because you're not passing a DateTime object. `pub_date = "2015-04-06T20:38:59Z"`, is a string, not an object.

Comment: ok, i get parsing it to a datetime format but even if i run the script with this data format i get the same error. i can pass the date in directly in SQL with this: `2015-04-06T20:38:59Z `, but not through django like this: `2015, 04, 06, 20, 38, 59`. I'm probably just being stupid, but I'm pretty new to django...

Comment: Passing a string to a `DateTimeField` is not an issue as long as it can be [parsed](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/utils/dateparse.py#L84) by Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you do not pass to `Article.objects.get_or_create` the data needed to create a new object in case none already exists.

What you need to do is (see the [documentation for get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)):

```
article = Article.objects.get_or_create(
    article_title=article_title,
    pub_date=pub_date,
    defaults={
        'id': id,
        'article_keywords': article_keywords,
        # etc...
    }
)[0]
```

The data passed using the `defaults` argument will only be used to create a new object. The data passed using other keyword arguments will be used to check if an existing object matches in the database.